# GCC fails to link static constexpr member variable under C++14

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, c++17

The following code compiles with c++17 but fails with c++14

> undefined reference to `Class<...>::name'

```
template<char... n>
class Class
{
public:
    static constexpr const char name[sizeof...(n) + 1] = {n..., '\0'};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Class<'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'>::name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is that so?

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0